# Is there a research exchange program for postdocs between UK and worldwide universities?

Tags: research-process, postdocs

I completed a PhD a couple of years ago and am looking at postdocs abroad, but not in my original field, so my advisors aren't able to suggest good places to apply to. Are there any programmes (official or unofficial) where a UK PhD is highly regarded that facilitate exchanges of academics between UK and worldwide universities? I'm thinking US and China to start with.

Comment: What fields are you coming from and going to?

Comment: Computational Fluid Dynamics (although I don't understand that much about it because I take a mathematical modelling approach) to mathematical modelling of anything.

Answer (score 2):

[Marie Skłodowska-Curie Individual Fellowships](http://ec.europa.eu/research/mariecurieactions/about-msca/actions/if/index_en.htm) fund individuals with PhDs to go and do a postdoc research project at another university for a while. If you are interested in the US/China, then you would be looking at the Global Fellowships, which fund a period of study outside the EU (typically 2 years) followed by a year back in an EU country to transfer the knowledge learned back into Europe. The scheme is highly competitive. You would need to make arrangements with appropriate host institutions yourself.

Answer (score 1):

British Council "Newton grants" for travel might be along the lines of what you're asking for. [1]

They are generally shorter than you might be looking for (up to 6 months), and have a formal application call process etc.

You would need to be affiliated with your university to get one though - they're not for finding a postdoc abroad, rather for a finite duration research exchange to collaborate. For that reason it may not be what you're looking for.

As a postdoc, you might be working on one specific project, perhaps with industrial relevance. In that case, you might find your PI isn't keen on losing you for a period of time. On the other hand, if you're part of a team doing more academically funded work, they may like the idea.

From personal experience though, these grants tend to require you to have identified a partner institution to visit and do research with, along with the project you wish to work on, and the expected outcomes.

[1]  http://www.britishcouncil.org/education/science/travel-grants

Comment: That looks great thanks! I can think of a few projects up to 6 months which continue doctoral work, although as I'm not affiliated to my old university, potentially I could affiliate to a local one as a visiting scholar and then apply to Newton grants.

Comment: Only problem is my main collaborator from that research is in Norway, not a listed country... :(

Comment: That could potentially work, although my instinct is that you would need to be a more permanently tied person first. From my memory of the program (albeit in the opposite direction, where a scholar visited our institution), he remained employed and paid by his host institution, and the grant covered the costs incurred in the exchange. These opportunities are fairly competitive, and someone working as a contracted researcher will normally appear more attractive than a visiting researcher, in my opinion.